# division function random integer need quotient and remainder printed out

Tags: c++, function

HI i wrote this code to have program , while using random integer less than 100 => divide the function , return qoutient and remainder and print them in output, but seems i do not work can you please help which part is wrong.

```
    #include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

using namespace std;
 int division(int& remainder,int qoutient)
{ 
int dividant;
int divisor;
    int quotient=dividant/divisor;      
   int remainder=dividant%divisor;
}

int main()
{
    int dividant =(rand()%99);
    int divisor =(rand()%99);
    int qoutient;
    int remainder_result;
    srand(time(NULL));
    do{qoutient=division(dividant,divisor);
    cout<<"this is q:"<<qoutient<<endl;
    cout<<"remainder"<<remainder_result<<endl;}
    while(dividant>divisor);


    }
```

Comment: making multiple accounts to post the same questions over and over will get you nowhere. i suggest you do some studying instead of flooding stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

- your division function makes use of variables `divident` and `divisor` declared in main, which is out of bounds for the function and will result in an error. in order to use these variables you need to pass these into the function using parameters.
- you also declare your division function as void, returning nothing, yet use it an a statement in your do while loop. In order to have the function return a value you need to replace void with the type you want to return, in this can an `int`, and return a value at the end of the function.
- `srand(time(NULL))` is placed after the initial rand functions, meaning the rand functions will return the same value as rand isnt seeded yet, THEN seed rand afterwards. You need to place `srand(time(NULL))` before your `rand()` calls

I suggest you read up more on c++ concepts, you don't have much right in this program along with some pretty messy coding techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You have compilation errors.  Your division function references variables that were not declared.  You will need to either parametize those variables, or change your division function; whatever the case, the function cannot access the variables declared in main's scope.

Here's a compilation error/warning list from IDEOne:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘void division(int&, int)’:
prog.cpp:11: error: ‘dividant’ was not declared in this scope
prog.cpp:11: error: ‘divisor’ was not declared in this scope
prog.cpp:11: warning: unused variable ‘quotient’
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:23: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
prog.cpp:25: error: ‘remainder’ was not declared in this scope
prog.cpp:28: error: expected `;' before ‘}’ token
prog.cpp:20: warning: unused variable ‘remainder_result’
```

Once you fix those errors, please let us know how it goes.  I also recommend you heed the warnings as they likely indicate other problems in the code.

Comment: i fixed some errors but still have problem , would you correct my whole code please?

Answer (score 0):

There were quite a few problems with the code, so I may have misunderstood what you were trying to do.  Here's the fixed code based on my understanding.  I took the liberty of changing your output so it shows the data for the full operation, so you can check the results:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void division(int dividend, int divisor, int& quotient, int& remainder)
{ 
    quotient = dividend / divisor;      
    remainder = dividend % divisor;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));    
    int dividend = rand() % 99;
    int divisor = rand() % 99;
    int quotient, remainder;
    division(dividend, divisor, quotient, remainder);
    cout << dividend << "/" << divisor << " = " << quotient << " remainder: " << remainder << endl;
    return 0;
}
```